# MySQL Index usage for ORDER BY LIMIT query

Tags: mysql

I'm using "users" table with over 2 millions records. The query is:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1 ORDER BY firstname LIMIT $start,30
```

"firstname" column is indexed. Getting first pages is very fast while getting last pages is very slow.

I used EXPLAIN and here are the results:

for

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `firstname` LIMIT 10000 , 30
```

I'm getting:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  users   index   NULL    firstname   194     NULL    10030
```

But for

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `firstname` LIMIT 100000 , 30
```

I'm getting

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  users   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2292912     Using filesort
```

What's the issue?

Comment: Try running `ANALYZE TABLE users` statement and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use limit to page that far into your dataset.

You'll get **much** better results by using range queries.

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE firstname >= last_used_name 
ORDER BY firstname 
LIMIT 30
```

Where `last_used_name` is one that you already seen (I'm assuming that you do batch processing of some sort). You will get more accurate results if you do range queries on a column with unique index. This way you won't get the same record twice.

When you do

```
LIMIT 100000 , 30
```

MySQL essentially does the same as in

```
LIMIT 100030
```

Only it doesn't return first 100 thousands. But it sorts and reads them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I'm using this for paginating the list. Getting  last_used_name to create a link would make my code more difficult. Would be happy to get some good solution

Comment: There ain't no such thing as free lunch, you know. Either you optimize your code, or suffer from slow `LIMIT`. I'll keep an eye on this post, maybe other solutions will emerge.

Answer (score 0):

For `*` queries without WHERE condition MySQL often does not use any indexes.

The following query should be much faster and make use of the index:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT user_id
  FROM users
  WHERE 1
  ORDER BY firstname
  LIMIT $start, 30) ids
JOIN users
USING (user_id);
```

`user_id` is the primary key.